# MYSQL query - trying to build HTML table from extern MySQL databse

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

I am a beginner with PHP and MySQL connections but I am really closed to resolve that issue I already spent some time on it. I had no problem with databases I made, but this one is an extern database from one of my client and he wants to builkd an HTML table from DB queires. The data in database are completely mixed and added under the same column, that why it is co complicated to me to understand the SQL query syntax.

In the database I have all data in table called : trr_postmeta

```
meta_id post_id meta_key         meta_value
3515    1479    company_sidlo    Praha
3516    1479    company_ico      02925885
3517    1479    company_date     04/23/2014
3518    1479    company_price    29400
3519    1479    company_url      https://or.justice.cz/ias/ui/rejstrik-firma.vysled...
3520    1479    company_state    zamluvená
3530    1481    _edit_last       7
3531    1481    _edit_lock       1413898849:7
3532    1481    company_typ      s.r.o.
3533    1481    company_sidlo    Praha
3534    1481    company_ico      02925605
3535    1481    company_date     04/23/2014
3536    1481    company_price    26900
```

And for my HTML output I need something like this:

```
--------------------
ID | ICO      | Typ
--------------------
 1 | 64654664 | sro
--------------------
```

My SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT meta_id, meta_value FROM trr_postmeta WHERE meta_key =  "company_typ" AND meta_key = "company_ico" AND meta_key = "company_date" AND meta_key = "company_price" AND meta_key = "company_url" AND meta_key = "company_state";
```

But I think my syntax WHERE is functional just for the first condition. Could you help me what I am doing wrong. I think 99% is the SQL query syntax but I cant figure this out. I need to get this values of company_typ and company_ico etc. under one column.

Thanks

Comment: first your query will return nothing since you can  not have one matching row with all the `and` conditions, 2ndly the expected output is not clear how you have `id=1`, what is `ico` and how its `64654664` ?

Comment: So please, how can I consolidate all conditions after WHERE syntax? In database column "meta_key" there´s so much values and I need just 5 of them in my HTML table. I need more "meta_value" column values to be shown in my HTML tables and I need to select only rows with specific "meta_key" value - as company_sidlo, company_ico, company_date, company_price, company_url. The rest of rows I do not care. Data I wrote it is bad example, value company_ico represents the company ID 02925885 as you can see on the picture from phpmyadmin.

Comment: just use `WHERE meta_key in ('company_typ','company_ico',etc....)`

Comment: Ok that´s perfect, it does exactly what I want with one exception:) 
All data ares shown in one column. What I need is an HTML table with data in row. Example: 
ID | Company ID | Company Type | Company headquaters | (the same as : "company_id" | "company_type" | "company_loc" | etc.) - in one ROW not a column!! But maybe this is more about PHP, because I am using the Joomla module for handling the databases.

Comment: I see, added an answer check it.

Comment: Seeing as your desired result has nothing to do with your data set, why not  SELECT 1 id, 64654664 ico, 'sro' typ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be the time of year...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav_hell;

 CREATE TABLE eav_hell
 (meta_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,post_id INT NOT NULL
 ,meta_key  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
 ,meta_value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
 ,UNIQUE(post_id,meta_key)
 );

 INSERT INTO eav_hell VALUES
 (3515    ,1479    ,'company_sidlo','Praha'),
 (3516    ,1479    ,'company_ico','02925885'),
 (3517    ,1479    ,'company_date','04/23/2014'),
 (3518    ,1479    ,'company_price','29400'),
 (3519    ,1479    ,'company_url','https://or.justice.cz/ias/ui/rejstrik-firma.vysled...'),
 (3520    ,1479    ,'company_state','zamluvená'),
 (3530    ,1481    ,'_edit_last','7'),
 (3531    ,1481    ,'_edit_lock','1413898849:7'),
 (3532    ,1481    ,'company_typ','s.r.o.'),
 (3533    ,1481    ,'company_sidlo','Praha'),
 (3534    ,1481    ,'company_ico','02925605'),
 (3535    ,1481    ,'company_date','04/23/2014'),
 (3536    ,1481    ,'company_price','26900');

 SELECT post_id
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_typ' THEN meta_value END) company_typ  
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_sidlo' THEN meta_value END) company_sidlo 
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_ico' THEN meta_value END) company_ico  
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_date' THEN meta_value END) company_date 
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_price' THEN meta_value END) company_price
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_url' THEN meta_value END) company_url  
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'company_state' THEN meta_value END) company_state
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_edit_last' THEN meta_value END) _edit_last   
      , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_edit_lock' THEN meta_value END) _edit_lock   
   FROM eav_hell
  GROUP  
     BY post_id;

 +---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
 | post_id | company_typ | company_sidlo | company_ico | company_date | company_price | company_url                                           | company_state | _edit_last | _edit_lock   |
 +---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
 |    1479 | NULL        | Praha         | 02925885    | 04/23/2014   | 29400         | https://or.justice.cz/ias/ui/rejstrik-firma.vysled... | zamluvená     | NULL       | NULL         |
 |    1481 | s.r.o.      | Praha         | 02925605    | 04/23/2014   | 26900         | NULL                                                  | NULL          | 7          | 1413898849:7 |
 +---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

BTW, if using an EAV model such as this, then it's still a good idea to separate the values out into different tables (or at least columns) according to their data types - so dates go in a dates table, numbers in a numeric table, and strings into a strings table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want the row value as column header, I have created a small example you can modify it as per your requirement

```
mysql> create table trr_postmeta (meta_key varchar(100),meta_value varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into trr_postmeta values ('company_typ','ABC'),('company_ico','pic.jpg'),('company_date','2014-11-28'),('company_state','LA');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from trr_postmeta;
+---------------+------------+
| meta_key      | meta_value |
+---------------+------------+
| company_typ   | ABC        |
| company_ico   | pic.jpg    |
| company_date  | 2014-11-28 |
| company_state | LA         |
+---------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the query will look like

```
select 
group_concat(if(meta_key = 'company_typ',meta_value,null)) as 'Company Type', 
group_concat(if(meta_key = 'company_ico',meta_value,null)) as 'Company Icon',
group_concat(if(meta_key = 'company_state',meta_value,null)) as 'Company State' 
from trr_postmeta ;
```

The output will look like

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| Company Type | Company Icon | Company State |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| ABC          | pic.jpg      | LA            |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Solution is gettin closer and closer. Now I have all data in one row, but anyway. Is there any possible seperator which can divide it in to different rows. I mean, yes the first row has to contain all information about the first company, but than in database there is another company, which I need to get to second row and repeat all the informations like ID, Type, Icon, State and than got to third row and start with another company. When you look again into my database you will see. Thank you for my last question.

Comment: sorry just look on my picture from PHPMYADMIn, as you can see, there´s repeating values for: company_sidlo, company_ico and than on ID 3533 it is repeating (but this is informations for another company (which I need to get in the second ROW etc. Is that more clear, or I can paste a data from database to see the details.

Comment: id 3515 = this is information for first company = first row
id 3533 = this is for second company and second row etc.

Comment: make a select of `post_id` along with the other info and then finally do a `group by post_id`